# Camera render thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, camera

My applications viewpager is buggy as it lags and sometimes gets stuck. This obviously has to do with the camera api I have on one of the pages.

I have implemented a thread to handle camera.open, is there a way to render the views in a thread somehow as I'm guessing everything is being done on the ui thread at the moment.

I don't really know what I'm looking for basically. I've made an app with a working camera but do not know how to make it run more smooth.

Comment: Personally, I'd never put a camera preview in a `ViewPager`. Beyond that, use Traceview to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: @CommonsWare If snapchat can do it well without lagging, so can I!

Comment: I have never used SnapChat. However, bear in mind that you may be seeing something other than a `ViewPager` there. You might consider using **`uiautomatorviewer`** to determine what they are actually using.

Comment: @CommonsWare Always nice learning new stuff from ya! :)